# Transaction Finalization

Tags: metamask, consensus, finality

According to features of the Ethereum Consensus, the rollbacks of blocks are possible: the block (and so, its transactions) is considered as a finalized one if quite a long chain is built upon the block. But if I send a transaction using, for example, MetaMask, it says that the transaction is successful immediately, without waiting for finalization. Does it mean that the message given by MetaMask can be a fault and as a result, the transaction will not be added to the blockchain?

Comment: If someone has enough mining power, that person can revert the blocks, and revert your transaction even 1000 blocks after it is mined. It is all about computing power. That risk will stay until Proof of Stake adopted

Comment: checkout how it is done by googling "ethereum classic hit by 51% attack"